# 1 user model with student,tutor role + different profile for student, tutor?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

How to correctly setup a User model with 2 roles, and have 2 separate profile models for each of the roles? Im confused on how to implement. Currently im using this but it fails:

**models/user.rb**

```
  #  id                     :integer ( only important columns noted to save space)
  #  profile_id             :integer
  #  profile_type           :string(255) 

  belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true
```

**models/profile_student.rb:**

```
  #  user_id     :integer      
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

**models/profile_tutor.rb:**

```
  #  user_id     :integer   
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

How to correctly get the profile for a user??
for example using devise.

> @user = current_user.profile

Answer (score 1):

I would try having two types of users: student and tutor.  In order to do this, in your user table, have a column called type and put in a validation that ensures it is either student or tutor:

```
validates :type, :inclusion => {:in => ['student', 'tutor']}
```

Then create a Student model and a Tutor model.  In rails, 'type' is a special kind of attribute in which rails will know that it is referring to other models.  Then, in order to make profiles, you have two options.  You can either say that both a student and a tutor has_one :profile, or you can separate the types of profiles.

For example, you can do:

```
class Student < User
    has_one :profile
end

class Tutor < User
    has_one :profile
end
```

If both profiles have similar types of information, that may work for you.  However, if a tutor and student have considerably different profiles, try something like this:

```
class Student < User
    has_one :student_profile
end

class Tutor < User
    has_one :tutor_profile
end
```

and then create a separate model for each type of profile.

By using this 'type' column, you can make it so that students and tutors inherit all the methods and properties of users, but can also have their own distinct properties and methods.