# Devise + Multiple Models with different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good Morning All,

I'm have two models both generated with Devise and I'm trying to figure out how I can get them to log in through one login.

They have different fields and datasets in them and not sure how I would  allow both users to use the same login. I have read various posts about using CanCan but that requires the users role to be defined after registration and the user have different fields they need to fill in on sign up.

I don't know if anyone has done this.

Just to summarize:

- Two Models
- Different Required Fields
- All required on Signup
- Need to login through one signup.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered another question and I think it would help you.  If you have any questions about how to implement this for your models, please let me know.

[1 user model with student,tutor role + different profile for student, tutor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300198/1-user-model-with-student-tutor-role-different-profile-for-student-tutor/20306487#20306487)